# What is a word for a review of a review?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I need a word to describe a review that has been made on a review.

The review itself I will call a "review", but if someone reviews the reviews, what can I call this? I can't call it a review as well as that would be confusing.

I need a short understandable word for it. Any ideas?

Comment: call it commentary on the review.

Comment: I have to use one word for it, as I have limited space.

Answer (score 5):

A review of a review is still just a *review*.

You might  risk calling it a *meta-review*, but understand that you would thereby put yourself at some small risk of being misunderstood.

Comment: Why?  What's ambiguous about *meta-review*?

Comment: @Jez I didn't say it was ambiguous, but you wouldn't believe how many people don't know what *meta-* means.

Comment: I agree with tchrist. We don't have special words for "the review of a disaster preparedness plan," or "a review of a preflight checklist," or "a review of a sexual harassment policy," so why would we have a special word for "a review of a review?" The only difference is we could easily call those others a _plan review,_ a _checklist review_, and a _policy review_; meanwhile, a _review review_ might sound a little awkward. So, either simplify it to _review_, or else call it what it is: a _review of a review_.

Comment: This is all well and good, but I want to know what one calls a review of a review of a review!  You know, Mr. Uptight critiques Mrs. Blatherhead's review of "Lee Daniels' The Butler."  Mr. Blabbermouth comes along and critiques Mr. Uptight's critique of Mrs. Baltherhead.  Would that be a meta-meta-critique?  What if I were to come along and critique Mr. Blabbermouth's critique of . . .?

Comment: @rhetorician: You do that! Then I can break new recursive Lit Crit territory by writing my own *meta-???????* of your *???????*.

Comment: I disagree with meta-review, a review of a review is still a review it's not "beyond" a review. If we were to discuss the procedure of a review that would be meta review I think.

Answer (score 2):

You might use terms like *[survey](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/survey#Noun)*, *[overview](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overview#Noun)*, *[composite](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/composite#Noun)*, and *[compilation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compilation#Noun)*, if the idea is that the meta-review will be combining information from other reviews.  If, on the other hand, the meta-review is intended to assess the quality of an earlier review, call it a *[reevaluation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reevaluation#Noun)* (“A second or subsequent evaluation or rating”) or *[reassessment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reassessment)* (“a second or subsequent assessment”).

Also see terminology mentioned in cochrane-net's [Combining studies](http://www.cochrane-net.org/openlearning/html/mod12-2.htm) webpage, and in wikipedia's [Meta analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis) article.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write it so that it is clear at any time which review is being referred to, and/or introduce your own terminology, e.g.:

1. for the original review:
   a. original review
   b. source review
   c. 'review being reviewed'
   d. Fred Smith's review (where *Fred Smith* is replaced by the original reviewer's name)
2. for your review:
   a. second review
   b. 'review-of-review'
   c. my review (where *my* refers to you)

You need to be inventive here.